# Qual o signifcado do numeral fracional como adjetivo?

Tags: gramática, números

No dicionário, vê-se que *terça parte* e *quarta parte* significam um terço e um quarto. Também se usa *meia* assim, como *eu comi meia maçã*. Então pergunto, quais os significados destas frases, se estiverem corretas:

1. Terça maçã está boa, terça [maçã] está estragada e terça [maçã] está comida.
2. Os três quintos quartos estão arrumados, o resto está de um porco.
3. Eu quero comprar um cano com três meios de largura deste.
4. Ele ficou com cinco quartas heranças e eu fiquei com uma!
5. Vocês ganham (o/um) sexto lucro.

Se estiverem corretas e for possível, pergunto: existe um artigo correto para usar? Isto é, deve ser «um sexto lucro», «o sexto lucro» ou «sexto lucro»?

Comment: Não creio que alguém vá entender essas frases sem uma explicação prévia.  Creio que você quis dizer que "ele ficou com cinco quartos da herança e eu fiquei com um quarto"  Seria isso ?  Se é, não faz sentido.  Nenhum total é maior do que quatro quartos., cinco quintos ou seis sextos.

Comment: @Centaurus, por isso eu perguntei o significado. Mas eu creio que «terça herança» signifique um terço da herança, então, «duas terças heranças» seria dois terços da herança. Mas talvez não seja isso. Não sei.

Comment: Os três quintos quartos? Claramente  são, de cada um dos 3 andares do hotel, o quinto quarto desse andar. Portanto, os 3 "quarto n]umero 5 deste andar" dos 3 andares. Os 3 "quinto-quarto"s. 

Answer (score 1):

Com artigo definido (e.g., "**o** quarto bolo") eu diria que se entende o numeral como sendo ordinal ("4ᵒ") e não como fracionário ("¼"), então aqui pede-se o artigo indefinido e também a preposição "de": "um quarto do bolo", para indicar "1/4 bolo". Uma exceção é quando as partes são iguais numericamente mas não qualitativamente e, portanto, são distinguíveis, e.g., "o quarto mais velho da população" — embora "os 25% mais velhos da população" seja provavelmente mais claro.

"Meio" é um caso especial, ele admite o uso que você sugere ("meio bolo" é claramente "1/2 bolo"), mas mesmo ele tem outro significado quando precedido pelo artigo definido "o": "o meio" parece indicar o ponto central (embora "a metade" seja claro).

> 1. Terça maçã está boa, terça [maçã] está estragada e terça [maçã] está comida.

Me soa muito estranho usar "terço" dessa forma (que eu diria que apenas com "meio" funcionaria). Eu usaria "um terço (da)" ao invés de "terça", ou então "uma terça parte (da)".

> 2. Os três quintos quartos estão arrumados, o resto está de um porco.

Não vejo como entender "quintos quartos", ou se fala de quintos ou de quartos ou de "três quintos de um quarto" (igual a três vinte avos, 3/20). Ou, como comenta o ANeves, são os 5ᵒˢ quartos (um por andar) de um prédio com 3 andares.

> 3. Eu quero comprar um cano com três meios de largura deste.

Não é uma maneira usual de expressar que você quer um cano 50% maior, mas funciona, e a única correção que eu sugeriria é "de" -> "da" e, talvez, "diâmetro" ao invés de "largura".

> 4. Ele ficou com cinco quartas heranças e eu fiquei com uma!

É preciso um contexto complicado para essa frase estar correta. Por exemplo, tomando "quarto" como ordinal ao invés de fracionário, talvez essas duas pessoas, A e B, tenham 6 tios-avós, cada um com 4 filhos, todos deixando heranças para A e B; quando o último filho de cada tio-avô morre (i.e., o quarto do ramo a morrer), ele deixa para A ou B a "quarta herança" desse ramo da família — então em cinco desses casos a herança ficou com B ("ele") e em apenas um, com A ("eu").

Sem esse contexto de 24+ heranças, a correção mais direta seria "cinco quartas heranças" -> "cinco quartos da herança", mas ela não funciona aqui, pois o total da herança tem apenas quatro quartos.  Outra correção, mas que muda bastante a frase, é "cinco quartas heranças" -> "quatro quintos da herança".

> 5. Vocês ganham (o/um) sexto lucro.

O correto me parece "um sexto do lucro". Um contexto em que a frase poderia fazer sentido com "o sexto lucro" é um em que "sexto" é ordinal, há tipos diferentes de lucro (financeiro, emocional, social, etc.) e a palavra "tipo" fica implícita na frase.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, stafusa, mas eu não consegui ver a resposta à pergunta «qual o significado do numeral fracionário como adjetivo?».

Comment: Não entendi, @Schilive, você sabe que "um terço de" significa 1/3 de algo, acontece que o uso idiomático não é generalizável como o matemático, no sentido de que eu posso escrever "(1/3) maçã", mas não "terça maçã" - apenas algo como "um terço de/da maçã" é usado.

Comment: Stafusa, eu também nunca ouvi alguém usando “terça maçã”, mas isso não diz que esteja errado. Eu não sei o significado de “terço” como adjetivo. Apenas sei que ele existe, como em «terça parte», então, eu perguntei qual o significado como adjetivo. Talvez o tenhas respondido, mas eu não consegui ver.

Comment: Então, @Schilive eu procurei bastantinho algum lugar que falasse explicitamente que apenas como descrevo é certo, sem sucesso, então, sim, não tenho fonte que suporte minha afirmação - apenas achei inúmeros exemplos de fontes de gramáticas e congêneres (apenas online) e nem uma única exceção (i.e., nenhum caso do tipo "terça maçã"), por isso tive confiança em escrever a resposta - mas, sem dúvida, um embasamento melhor seria desejável.